# trying to understand how Redboot ransomware works

Tags: windows, malware, ransomware

[this sample](https://www.joesandbox.com/analysis/884768/0/html) is able to drop exes though I'm not sure how

the report indicates it calls CreateFileW though changing the call's outcome doesn't work

is Redboot using heaven's gate (or another technique) to bypass interference? how can I check what is it and the way it works?
thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I thought it's deemed a wiper instead of ransomware?!

Comment: hi, thanks!
it's also a wiper, yes, though it's identified as ransomware by many vendors